# mule filter not stopping flow processing, picks up after choice end tag

Tags: filter, mule

In this flow, I have verified that when the filter returns 'false' the flow continues anyway. But the payload is slightly different. I need to stop these messages completely.

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each"> 
            <choice doc:name="Choice"> 
                when expression="#[payload['event'] contains 'delete' ]"> 
                    <!-- this path is unrelated to this question -->  
                </when>  
                <otherwise> 
                    <flow-ref name="getMessages" doc:name="FlowToGetMessages"/>  
<!-- this (below) will extract the single row value (a Map) from the array returned from above flow -->
                    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/> 
                    <expression-filter expression="#[payload['activity'] != null && payload['activity'] != "" ]" doc:name="Block Empty Rows"/>
                    <custom-filter class="package.BlockNullAnnouncementEvents" doc:name="Block null"/>
                </otherwise>  
            </choice>
...
```

The next processor (after the choice) gets 
A) a single value if the message passes the filter test BlockNullAnnouncementEvents or 
B) an array with one value if the null is present and the filter fails the same test

This appears to me that, if a message fails the filter test, then the result of the call to the flow getMessages is returned to the top of the for-each which passes it on to the next part of the flow after the choice branch that contains the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After its execution the foreach will restore the original message as explained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Foreach)

If you want the execution to stop you should use a [message filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Filter) and configure the Throw On Unaccepted to true

Comment: Thank you ... the 'Throw On Unaccepted to true' is what I needed to know.

Comment: Hi @genjosanzo, I had a flow looks almost the same as op's but even with message filter and throw on unaccepted, I can see the flow still runs after the message filter throw the exception and if I put a logger after that <choice> block, I can see the payload being logged.